WEBM in video-tag is not playing properly in Safari 17.5
I am trying to loop a webm in a basic video tag but I notice that after the first run the video breaks. Starting the Video via the controls works for the first time but after that the playhead moves but the video is not playing anymore. Here is the example and the code looks like this:
<video controls>
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp9">
</video>


I've narrowed it down to Safari 17.5 because Chrome and Firefox worked fine for me and I know that older Versions of Safari also work. Also trying different combinations of flags did not resolve the issue. Experience says that it may be just a bug but I want to know if someone also is having the same issue since I can't find anything recent about it.

Solved it by adding a fallback like this:
`



`
Since I wanted to play the webm in the first place, i encode the mp4 with HEVC so every other browser falls back to the webm